# How do i rebuild a Selectize built dropdown after the Select its based on changes

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, selectize.js

I'm using backbone and selectize to build a dropdown after a collection is fetched from the server. When the collection is updated, so is the original select.

But selectize isnt updated. Here's my collectionReset that should be handling it correctly

```
collectionReset: function () {
            this.select = this.$el.find('#event-type-list').selectize({
                plugins: ['remove_button'],
                delimiter: ',',
                persist: false,
                create: false,
                score: function (search) {
                    return function (item) {
                        return 1 / item.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase());
                    };
                }
            })[0].selectize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured a work around in the end, ended up building the selectize dropdown the first time, then manually clearing it and adding new items on every subsequent change

```
collectionReset: function () {
            if(this.select == null) {
                this.select = this.$el.find('#event-type-list').selectize({
                    plugins: ['remove_button'],
                    delimiter: ',',
                    persist: false,
                    create: false,
                    score: function (search) {
                        return function (item) {
                            return 1 / item.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase());
                        };
                    }
                })[0].selectize;
            } else {
                this.select.clearOptions();
                for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.models.length; i++) {
                    var eventType = this.collection.models[i];
                    this.select.addOption({value:eventType.get('eventTypeId'),text:eventType.get('name')});
                }
            }
        }
```